# Shortcode Attribute

Tags: shortcode

I want to assign a title to my column shortcode.  Essentially, 
[column title="nameofcolumn"]content[/columntitle].  But I'm not quite sure what to do after the "=>" or after my div class of title.  I've looked for tutorials but I can't find anything specific enough for me to understand.

```
function column_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'title' => 'WHAT DO I ENTER HERE',
    ), $atts));
   return '<div class="third"><div class="title">DO I NEED SOME TEXT HERE?</div><hr/>' . $content . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode('one_third', 'column_shortcode');
```

EDIT:  Also I'd like to set my 1/3 columns under a row div so I can clear: both.  How can I accommodate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, you are kind in the right path, just need to know that the 'title' is a variable that will get and past the value, so you have to call it exactly where you wrote "DO I NEED SOME TEXT HERE", so it goes like this:

```
 function column_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'title' => 'WHAT DO I ENTER HERE',
 ), $atts));
 return '<div class="third"><div class="title">'. $title .'</div><hr/></div>';
}

add_shortcode('one_third', 'column_shortcode');
```

Notice where you have 'WHAT DO I ENTER HERE', is the default value it will take so probably you might want to leave it blank :)

UPDATE***

I didn't notice that call to the content you had in there, you don't need it, let me know if it goes well

Comment: That easy?  Wow haha I was trying so much nonsensical crap.  I'll check you off once the time limit lets me.  Thanks!

Comment: wait, I realized you have a mistake, I'm updating

Comment: Alright I'll keep checking on the thread.  Oh, also, do you know how to assign a row to those columns so I can use "clear: both" css?

Comment: I just fixed it, regarding to the clear, yes, you can add it wherever you want into the '', however I don't understand exactly what you want to do, you can also grab em into <li> tags, if you paste the html of the code you rae trying to achieve would be easier